# Get non-duplicate rows in sql

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, row

I am trying to get non-duplicate rows (except the primary id) from a database and I found it a little hard to do it because I am anxiously building the query and for some reason, it's not working.

Let's assume we have the following:

```
id  product_id claim_id
1   2         3
2   2         3
```

So I am trying to get only a single row.

Basically my query is:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE claim_id = 3
```

Tried to append to the query either GROUP BY claim_id and product_id but with no success.
Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Look into DISTINCT.
So it would be SELECT DISTINCT(product_id), id from table where claim_id = 3

Comment: I have a complicated query that is kind of general, and basically it selects all the rows, some of: 
$query = sprintf("SELECT %s.* FROM %s %s %s %s %s;"

Comment: @IleNea Your last comment isn't very helpful. That is c (or whatever language) code that generates a tsql statement using values that could be anything. Forget about how the query is created and focus on the query that you need to generate the correct resultset. Once you have that, you can then attempt to fit it into your application. In addition, the term "non-duplicate" can mean different things to different people. A good starting point is to identify the resultset you desire from the database using on the sample data you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `distinct` modifier:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, product_id, claim_id
FROM   mytable
WEHRE  claim_id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to also get one of the IDs.  For example, if you want to save only non-duplicates, but keep a key around to join to another table.  I like using windowing functions for such tasks.

```
SELECT X.ID, X.product_id, X.claim_id
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product_id, Claim_id ORDER BY ID) AS row_num,
            ID,
            product_id,
            claim_id
    FROM dbo.TABLE
) AS X
WHERE x.row_num = 1
```